# RegionPlot3D behaving badly

Tags: graphics3d

If you go to the documentation page for RegionPlot3d, in the Scope/Presentation section you will find this code:

```
RegionPlot3D[
 z^2 - 1 <= x^2 + y^2 <= z^2 + 1, {x, -2.3, 2.3}, {y, -2.3, 
  2.3}, {z, -2, 2}, PlotLabel -> z^2 - 1 <= x^2 + y^2 <= z^2 + 1, 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Directive[Specularity[White, 10], Opacity[0.85], Purple], 
 PlotPoints -> 20, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
 AxesEdge -> {{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {-1, 0}}, Mesh -> False]
```

which looks cool and works well.
A little further down you will find:

```
RegionPlot3D[
 z^2 - 1 <= x^2 + y^2 <= z^2 + 1, {x, -2.3, 2.3}, {y, -2.3, 
  2.3}, {z, -2, 2}, PlotTheme -> "Business"]
```

and immediately afterwards:

```
RegionPlot3D[
 z^2 - 1 <= x^2 + y^2 <= z^2 + 1, {x, -2.3, 2.3}, {y, -2.3, 
  2.3}, {z, -2, 2}, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

As you can see both these last two examples do not work so well. The solid looks "chipped".

Can somebody explain this? Is this a known bug?

Comment: try adding the option `PlotPoints -> 100`?

Comment: @kglr yes! mistery solved! As a matter of fact PlotPoints -> 18 is enough and indeed the first example uses PlotPoints -> 100. I still wonder why Wolfram does not correct those last two examples. If you like to post an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default setting for `PlotPoints` is `15` as can be seen using `Trace`:

```
Trace[RegionPlot3D[z^2 - 1 <= x^2 + y^2 <= z^2 + 1,
   {x, -2.3, 2.3}, {y, -2.3,  2.3}, {z, -2, 2}, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"], 
  HoldPattern[ PlotPoints -> _Integer], TraceInternal -> True] // Flatten
```

> ```
> {PlotPoints -> 15, PlotPoints -> 15}
> ```

Using a larger value, say `50`, gives a better picture:

```
RegionPlot3D[ z^2 - 1 <= x^2 + y^2 <= z^2 + 1, 
  {x, -2.3, 2.3}, {y, -2.3, 2.3}, {z, -2, 2}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

and with `PlotTheme -> "Business"`  we get

[image]